# Is there a popular translation for brain-freeze, yet?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there currently a well known translation for *brain-freeze*? There doesn't seem to be a page for it on Vikipedio or Vikivortaro so there might not be a popular word for it yet, right? If not, does anyone have a good compound that could be used for it?

Comment: How about _cerbfrosto_?

Comment: That's what I initially thought of, but the big problem with that compound is that it isn't logically deducible, it's just a loan translation from English. If I heard that word and didn't know the English word that it came from, I might think of snow particles from a preserved brain (or something like that) more than I'd think of a headache that you get from consuming something cold.

Comment: In which case there is no choice but to paraphrase it like _kapdoloro pro enstomakigi malvarma substanco_ -- in German there is no word for it either, so a native German speaker would need the full explanation and could not deduce the meaning from a single word.

Comment: Why is the word "yet" in the question?

Comment: Because I'm sure (or was, I'm becoming less so) that since this is a simple concept that most people have experienced, a word will be necessitated and created eventually. I wanted to know if there was already one however, since I haven't seen it and have become curious. It doesn't seem like there is an often used word yet, and since some natural languages don't have a word for it either, perhaps it isn't as necessary of a word to have as I first thought. I still think that it would be useful to have anyway, though.

Comment: Remember that Esperanto is 130 years old. If it's obvious, it's probably already happened by now.

Comment: At an Esperanto meeting last week someone asked me this same question. I said *frostofrapo* thanks to the discussion here. I'm glad this question was asked in S.E.

Answer (score 9):

What about ***glacia kapdoloro***? I’m sure most people have experienced this, so I don’t think we need to be overly pedantic in the explanation. :-) (Like ”*promalvarmaĵglutada glacisento encerba*”!)

> *I chewed an ice-cube and got an instant brain-freeze.*
>
> Mi maĉis glacikubon kaj ekhavis glacian kapdoloron.

Also note the alternative English wording *[Ice cream headache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice_cream_headache)*.

Comment: The principle of *neceso kaj sufiĉo* would suggest saying simply *kapdoloro* in your example. Further, *glacia kapdoloro* is an "icy headache". Also note that there's a difference between being detailed and pedantic.

Comment: Have you ever experienced a brain-freeze? It sure is a headache, but also a very special kind of headache. *Glacia* specifies that it’s not just a normal headache. Yes, I’m aware being pedantic and detailed are two different things – sorry if anybody got upset. My point is that we depart from a very simple English expression (brain + freeze), and I don’t see the need of explaining it lengthily. Even if many cultures don’t have ice-cubes, all people have brains that react to the ingestion of very cold stuff. It’s a very human concept, and if ”Englishers” can describe it easily, so can we.

Answer (score 2):

How about ***sfenopalata ganglioneuralgio***?

We could also coin a portmanteau pseudo-compound ***glacikranio*** (from *glacio* and *hemikranio*.)

Remember that Esperanto is supposed to make communication easier. The first question you should ask is whether "brain freeze" or "ice cream headache" is a universal concept. A little surprisingly, this discussion suggests that it might not be:

https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/3ndpab/what_do_other_countrieslanguages_call_a_brain/

Maybe English speakers put more ice in their Coca Cola.

The Wikipedia article (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice_cream_headache) links to several national articles, most of which are described with phrases or compounds that would suggest using a descriptive compound or phrase in Esperanto:

- Glaci-kapdoloro
- Kapdoloro pro rapida trinkado de io malvarma.

The Italian translations (*l'emicrania da gelato, mal di testa da gelato, o cervello ghiacciato*) are interesting because they're so varied - and also make a reference to ***hemikranio*** which I did above, mostly as a scientific-sounding joke.

Comment: Saluton Tomaso: As far as I can tell, most languages don’t have a word for *twerking*. However, due to the global impact of American pop culture, (young) people all over the world know the English word. Why should we deny them an Esperantigo – isn’t that just making communication more difficult? Shakespeare, methinks, did not talk about ”brain-freeze”either – it’s a concept that’s been popularized through American tv serials etc. Even if there’s no word for it in Slovakian, I’m sure many youngsters on the streets of Bratislava are familiar with it, even if *we* don’t like the americanisation.

Comment: I'm not sure what I said that could have been taken as a suggestion that we shouldn't have a way to say brain freeze in Esperanto. Indeed, I gave four different suggestions on how to say it.

Comment: I’m sorry if I misunderstood you, then. Let me just point out that ”brain-freeze” is made of ordinary, everyday-English roots (’brain’ and ’freeze’). Your suggestions are **not** made of ordinary, everyday-Esperanto roots. Hence, I thought you were being sarcastic or ironic. An Esperantigo should, IMHO, be just as simple as the original. **glacikranio** could work, though – except that I think most people hearing it would think of a skull made of ice. ’brain-freeze’ is ”everyday-ish”, while your suggestions – with all respect –sound a bit more like scientific explanations.

Answer (score 1):

The way Stack Exchange is supposed to work, the best information gets voted to the top. In this case, *glacia* (icy) is clearly not the best way to express this, since the rules of Esperanto word-formation would require this to be a compound (*glaci-kapdorloro*) and not an adjective with a noun.

Therefore I posted this question to my personal Facebook page, and also to the group Lingva Konsultejo. What follows are the question I asked and the responses I received. The original public thread is here.

https://www.facebook.com/groups/konsultejo/permalink/1452085794816438/

---

### Kion oni nomas la kapdoloron kio sekvas la manĝado de malvarmaj aferoj. Iu proponis "glacia kapdoloro" sed laŭ mi la doloro ne estas glacia.

- **Krioalgio**
- frostiĝa kapdoloro
- cerbnefunkcio
- **frostofrapo**
- **proglacia kapdoloro**
- promalvarma kapdoloro
- en Porto-Riko oni **ne havas specifan vorton** por tio.
- Ankau ni ne (en Hispanujo)
- glaciaĵ-kapdorloro
- „ból głowy po szybkim zjedzeniu/wypiciu czegoś zimnego” (**„kapdoloro post rapida manĝo/trinko de io malvarma”**).
- Mi fakte ne sciis ke tio estas universala doloro
- glaci-doloro (Sed la glacio ne de doloras min.)
- **Aspektas kultur-specifa nocio.** Ne ĉiuj kulturoj rimarkas la fenomenon (se ĝi entute ekzistas). Ni povas diri "заморозишь мозги" (*zamoroziŝ mozgi', "vi frostigos la cerbon"), sed **ne nomas la doloron iel aparte**.
- **brejnfrizo** ;-)
- En la sveda oni povas nomi ĝin "isskalle" = glacikapo / **glacikranio.**
- Cerbofrostiĝo

Comment: Dankon pro la laboro. :-) ”Frostofrapo” ege plaĉas al mi. Ĝi estas simile simpla kiel la Angla vorto.

Comment: Glaci-doloro ankaŭ estas bona (laŭ mi).

Comment: Ni samopinias pri **frostofrapo**.